# codeigniter - how to remove http://localhost/social/pages/envi --> pages where pages is php in social/application/controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Here is my pages.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
}
public function event()
{
    $this->load->view('event');

}
public function envi()
{
    $this->load->view('envi');
}
public function tour()
{
    $this->load->view('tour');
}
```

Can you guys help me out when click on button `localhost/social/pages/envi`  this is opens.. but i need that file should be access and url should localhost/envi how to do that can u guys help me

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Index.php/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi ShanmukSrinivas Gandepalli,

There a file routes.php in the config folder, open it add define your action here

Like below, here home is controller name and aboutus is method name. Now you can call this by aboutus no need to add contoller in the url.

```
 $route['aboutus'] = 'page/aboutus';
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways for doing this
Like you can set apache rule in .htaccess file **OR**

Define your routing in this file
application/config/routes.php

Comment: how to define the routing

Comment: Put this line of code in routes.php

$route ['envi'] = "social/pages"; 

URL will go like this
http://localhost/envi

Answer (score 1):

Put this line of code in routes.php

$route ['envi'] = "social/pages";

URL will go like this
http://localhost/envi